# Ресурсы из другого приложения

Tags: android, java

Как получить ресурсы из другого (моего) приложения?

```
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent("PACKAGE_NAME");
    List<ResolveInfo> ThemePacks = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(myIntent, 0);
```

PackageManager.getResourcesForActivity и PackageManager.getResourcesForApplication не помогают. При обращении к ресурсам получаем "Unable to find resource ID"

P.S.: Ресурсы получаю типов style и  drawable

Answer (score 1):

Хм, смотря какие ресурсы. Вообще-то они компилируются(те что в res), а те, что не в папке res, а например в assets можно получить распаковав apk-файл как zip-архив.

Добавлю: я думаю вы неверно задачу ставите, исходя из данного вопроса. То бишь есть архитектурный изъян.

Comment: а если идти через SharedUId? Все описаное мной выше описано в нескольких статьях, но там неинформативно и в некоторой степени неприменимо в моей ситуации. Например http://habrahabr.ru/post/149564/#habracut используют темы (то есть style ресурсы) но тольсо с заменой цвета, мне же нужно чтобы тема тянула не @color, а @style и @drawable

Comment: у меня вопрос зачем вообще это делать?

Comment: Темы для приложения. В темах используются стили с фоновыми изображениями.

Comment: нужное вам решение ответом ниже - Android Library.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендованный способ разделения ресурсов это создание разделяемого обоими приложения [Android Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html) или как альтернатива создания `ContentProvider`'а который будет публиковать свои ресурсы наружу

Comment: Android Library не подходит:
"После того, как проект Android обозначается как проект библиотеки, он не может быть установлен ​​на устройстве". Да и к тому же получается обратная зависимость. Мне нужно в основном приложении получать данные из дополнительного, а если делать именно так, то в основном приложении нужно прописывать все библиотели, и компилироваться они будут с ним.
Про контент провайдер еще не смотрел.